# Laravel - Sentinel User is not the same as eloquent User

Tags: php, laravel, sentinel

I am using Laravel and Sentinel for my authentication.

Authentication works fine, I can log in using Sentinel and get back a User and I can see all of the User's fields.

However, I cannot access it's relationships (other than the Sentinel roles).

```
$user = Sentinel::findById($userId);
dd($user->telephones); // returns null

$user = App\User::find($userId);
dd($user->telephones); // displays a dump of the associated eloquent collection
```

Is there a way to retrieve the eloquent User from Sentinel so I can look at it's relationships?

Comment: Did you set the user model in the sentinel config file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `User` model extend Sentinel `EloquentUser`.

```
class User extends EloquentUser
```

And in your `catalyst sentinel config` set user model like-

```
'users' => [
    'model' => 'App\User',
],
```

And don't forget to run-

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: That @Sohel0415 makes good sense, thank you. Although I wonder if I lose anything from the Sentinel model by doing this? Is there a reason they didn't set it up like that by default?

Comment: if it solves your problem, then upvote it and accept it as it may help others later

Comment: I will, but any ideas if I lose anything by doing it this way?

Comment: As your data in your users table and its not going anywhere, then there is nothing to lose in my sense. Actually your functionality will remain same as you are extending eloquent user.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why they don't do that by default then!

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks